# date related query design in MS-Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table which stores prescription records of patients.
To print the prescription I designed a report based on a prescription-date query where parameter is given as Date() in criteria column to print prescription of a patient given on the today's date. In spite of correct query design as shown in help of MS-Access, the records are not seen except "Todays Date".

Fields in table are Prescription no-indexed, PNO-patient no-indexed, prescription date- which is Todays date-Date(), drug name, quantity and dosage.
I need to enter drugs and print them immediately to hand over to patients.
I dont know why its not working
Please suggest a solution. I dont have knowledge of syntax, I use built in libraries in MS-Access and have programmed forms, querys, tables and reports and macros to run the patient database.

email ID  -    san_sgprasadi@dataone.in

Dr Prasadi

Comment: We need more to work on. Database layout, code, scripts, anything you can provide which is not confidential.

Comment: If you open the table in DataSheet View and click into one of the prescription-date fields does it show a time element?

Comment: I would make sure that date isn't getting confused as Now() somehow.  If you're using query design, try something in the Criteria of that field like `Between [StartDate] and [EndDate]` so that it prompts you to enter dates when you run the query or report.